# How can I have a button shown in the main view in vs code extensions next to language elements?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I want to write an extension and before really getting into it, I was wondering if there is a way to add a clickable icon with a handlable callback on the main text editor window, next to language elements, for example, right side of function names or variables?

For example, in the attached picture, the green button is rightmost of the window to the function name run(), I want something like that, that the user can click on it. So, anywhere there is a function definition, I could have a button next to that just like the image?

[image]

Comment: Usually you should choose from a few extension points, such as code actions or code lens, https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api not creating your own.